# ASP.NET string interpolation for attributes

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am simply trying to insert a variable into a favicon link

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%=Favicon%>" type="image/x-icon" />
```

It works when I don't have to quote the text. 
I have Favicon defined in the Page_Load and I'm using interpolation to generate the page title without problem.

Comment: What is actually not working? Are you getting errors? Is the favicon not displaying, what is the rendered HTML if there are no errors? Show how and what you are setting to `Favicon` and are there any quotes in that string?

Comment: in the source: href="&lt;%=Favicon %>" and Favicon is a url in quotes as defined in my Webconfig. I'm only having trouble with interpolating values that need to be quoted.

Comment: If you're really getting `%lt;` in the rendered html that is very weird. Try deleing the open angle bracked and type it back. Also try using single quotes `'` instead of double `"`

Comment: exactly the same with single quotes. I also tried to add quotes to the string in the cs file by adding "\"" to each end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what I found. It seems to be an issue with the `link` tag in the head. Copy the exact same code and put it in the body and it works. Take the following and put in the head and it populates as expected: `<div id="<%= Favicon %>"><%= Favicon %></div>`

Work arounds:

Take quotes out of the element and put them in the string:

**Markup:** note no quotes for `href`

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href=<%= Favicon %>  type="image/x-icon" />
```

**C#**: quotes added to string

```
public string Favicon = "\"//www.alink.com/toAnImage.ico\"";
```

I think [Scotty's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495037/asp-net-string-interpolation-for-attributes/25496257#25496257) may be better though

Comment: This worked! Did not do the div thing and did not have to add the quotes to the c# string. Worked without. Pretty silly it wont take a link in the head, where it belongs.

Comment: I agree, odd and unexpected behaviour. I'd add quotes to your string. YOu can probably get away without though, unless you end up with URLs with spaces in them, in which case you will need to use quotes or escape the spaces. The "div thing" was just an illustration of why this is odd

Comment: This worked! I ended up surrounding in single quotes <link rel="shortcut icon" href='<%=Favicon %>'  type="image/x-icon" /> and for the css: <link rel="stylesheet" href='<%=GlobalStyleSheet %>'  type="text/css"/>

Comment: Now it stopped working, I've reverted to my long workaround which generates the links from scratch http://stackoverflow.com/a/25496929/1550052

Comment: Adding the single quotes in the markup would have killed it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead...

Page:

```
<link runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" id="favIcon" />
```

Page_Load:

```
favIcon.Attributes.Add("href", Page.ResolveUrl("~/PathTo/somecool.ico"));
```

Comment: I did try this (from google search) before and failed. So I think its another problem. I'm using 'fav' as the id. And I get "The name 'fav' does not exist in the current context". Its on my master page and in the header if thats any help.

Comment: Are you looking for 'fav' in the Page_Load of the masterpage or a content page? If it's a content page, you'll need to use
    var fav = Page.Master.FindControl("fav")

Comment: Master: Mainframe.master is where the link is, and Mainframe.master.cs Page_Load is where I'm trying to get it.

Comment: My code works fine in my Master page. Have you tried copy and pasting my code in?

Comment: Could not get that to work. the id does not register in the cs page. I am trying to get it via an HtmlHead object...

Comment: Makesure to add `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath=[Path To You Master] %>` in the content pages

Comment: I'll keep this one in my back pocket. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `runat=server`

```
<link runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="<%=Favicon%>" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming from ruby this seems a bit like overkill just to avoid allowing dynamic attributes within a website.

I did not really need to do this, just wanted to.

This is what I did, which could be totally the wrong way. I have no idea.

I deleted the style and favicon links entirely in the aspx.

In Page_Load:

```
    public string GlobalStyleSheet, Favicon;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalStyleSheet = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GlobalStyleSheet"];

        Favicon = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Favicon"];

        HtmlHead head = (HtmlHead)Page.Header;
        HtmlLink faviconLink = new HtmlLink();
        HtmlLink cssLink = new HtmlLink();

        faviconLink.Href = Favicon;
        faviconLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "shortcut icon");
        faviconLink.Attributes.Add("type", "image/x-icon");
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(faviconLink);

        cssLink.Href = GlobalStyleSheet;
        cssLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssLink);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean, "avoid dynamic attributes within a web site?" Also, FYI, `<%= x%>` is not string interpolation. It's a shorthand for `Response.Write(x);`.

Comment: Whatever dude, same thing in the end. Try ruby.

Comment: No, it's not the same thing. I know Perl and several other languages which include string interpolation. This is a totally different process, and is not used to build up a string - it's part of the process that will build up the HTML that will be sent to the browser.